# route values are being passed after code execute in asp net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AnswerExam(int examId)
        {
            var obb = onlineExamDBContext.QuestionAndAnswers.Where(x => x.ExamId == examId);
            return View(await obb.ToListAsync());
        }

<a asp-action="AnswerExam" asp-route-id="@item.ExamId">Attempt</a>
```

but later after code executes i can see the id being passed in the url
https://localhost:44395/CandidateExam/AnswerExam/16

but tht id 16 is not being passed to the action method?? what cud be the reason? please help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AnswerExam(int examId)
        {
            var obb = onlineExamDBContext.QuestionAndAnswers.Where(x => x.ExamId == examId);
            return View(await obb.ToListAsync());
        }
```

Found the issue. The **examId** in above action method should match with the route values such tht

asp-route-**examId**="@item.ExamId"